# Fixed position with hover

Tags: html, css

Well I have a navigation with a fixed position with a list inside, which I want to change color on a hover. But this doesn't work because of the fixed position of the navigation. Is there a way to get around this?

Here is my example

```css
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 1px;
}

.nav-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1500px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.nav-right {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; 
    margin: -30px 130px 0px 0px;
    height: 60px;
}


.nav-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 20px;
}

.nav-menu li:last-child {margin: 0}

.nav-menu li:hover { cursor: pointer;}

.nav-left {
    float: left;
    color: #02c576;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 15pt;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    height: 24px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -12px 0px 0px 130px;
}

.nav-button {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
           <div class="nav-inner">
               <div class="nav-left">
                   <div class="logo">
                        <p>Company Name</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="nav-right">
                   <div class="nav-menu">
                        <ol>
                            <li data-menu="Link1">Link1</li>
                            <li data-menu="Link2">Link2</li>
                            <li data-menu="Link3">Link3</li>
                            <li data-menu="Link4">Link3</li>
                        </ol>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="nav-button">
                   <img src="Images/menu.png">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you try to give your li width and height?

Comment: Yes I did, but doesn't seem to work

Comment: You likely need to set the color on the `nav li a` because default colors are usually applied to the `a` tag

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: pls add your html too

Comment: make a jsfiddle or jsbin, so that it can easily reproducible by others.

Comment: Added the code :D

Answer (score 1):

Well after trying and trying I added a z-index in the .nav css and it worked... finally! I have no clear explanation for why it worked, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way currently in CSS alone to select a parent of a child. 
The best way I can think of to do this, or at least the simplest would require a little JS.

Simple add a data attribute to your list items, and a JS event that on hover passes the value of the data attribute as a class to the fixed navigation. That class would control color.

Have a go yourself, if you struggle post some code and we can fix it.

Comment: in css you can just use `element:hover{ color: #123456; }` to apply the style to the individual elements on hover. See the snippet in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I thought he wanted to change the background of the fixed navigation on hover of a child.

Answer (score 0):

well, you code works fine for me
[js fiddle linke](https://jsfiddle.net/6r22fbyb/)
I saw your code and if you don't want to use `<a>` tag you have to add

```
.nav-menu li:hover{
color:#fff;
}
```

simple code

```css
nav { width: 100px; height: 80px; position: fixed; } 
nav li { display: inline-block; } 
nav li:hover { color: white; }
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li>dhh</li>
  <li>fs</li>
  <li>ss</li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me with your code (all I did was actually put the `<a>` tags inside the `<li>` elements, since that was what your code was targeting.)

```css
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 1px;
}

.nav-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1500px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.nav-right {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; 
    margin: -30px 130px 0px 0px;
    height: 60px;
}


.nav-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 20px;
}

.nav-menu li:last-child {margin: 0}

.nav-menu li a:hover { 
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}

.nav-left {
    float: left;
    color: #02c576;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 15pt;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    height: 24px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -12px 0px 0px 130px;
}

.nav-button {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
           <div class="nav-inner">
               <div class="nav-left">
                   <div class="logo">
                        <p>Company Name</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="nav-right">
                   <div class="nav-menu">
                        <ol>
                            <li data-menu="Link1"> <a href=#>Link1</a> </li>
                            <li data-menu="Link2"><a href=#>Link2</a></li>
                            <li data-menu="Link3"><a href=#>Link3</a></li>
                            <li data-menu="Link4"><a href=#>Link4</a></li>
                        </ol>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="nav-button">
                   <img src="Images/menu.png">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad I was trying something and I forgot to change that one. It's now fixed in the post

Comment: @FlyingUnderpants Edit again, and add `color: red` to the `.nav-menu li:hover  {` section. You'll see your code works fine

Comment: I really don't understand, I see it works fine on the snippet, but when I edit it in my own document is doesn't work

Comment: I assume they will actually be working links, so try adding the `<a>` element inside the `<li`> tags, and apply the `:hover` style to the `<a>` tags. I can't see the `color: ` styling applied in your code above on the `:hover`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've tried is putting a filler element inside the first element, and target styling hover for that inner element.

Comment: While that may be the way to do it, this answer doesn't provide any code, which is probably what the OP is looking for.